# How to check if I have 'svn' bridge install in my git

Tags: git, git-svn, macports

I have 'git' install, but I am not sure if I have the 'svn' bridge install as well ("the part to run 'git svn').

So I tried to do `sudo port install git-core +svn` on Mac.
But I end up getting:

```
--->  Activating git-core @1.6.3.3_0+doc+svn
Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error: Another version of this port   (git-core @1.6.3.3_0+bash_completion+doc+svn) is already active.
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

So how can I check if I have 'svn' bridge installed in my git?

Thank you.

Comment: just run "git svn --help". Does it work? If not, then you don't have it. However it looks like you have the shell auto completion for it. I don't know why it's conflicting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can always try running `git svn` and seeing if an executable is found.

However, your output from MacPorts shows that you *do* have the `svn` variant installed, which means the git-svn bridge is present. You can tell this because MacPorts reports that `git-core @1.6.3.3_0+bash_completion+doc+svn` is installed. `git-core` is the name of the port, `@1.6.3.3_0` is the version, and anything with a leading `+` sign (`+bash_completion`, `+doc`, and `+svn`) are the variants installed with the port. If you want to force a reinstall, run

```
$ sudo port -f install git-core +svn
```

(notice the `-f` flag passed to the `port` program), although this shouldn't be necessary in this case, since `git-core` (with the `svn` variant) is already installed.

Comment: `which git-svn` might not work. In general, newer versions of Git *only* have the `git` binary in the search path and all the other `git-*` binaries are hidden away in a separate path.

Comment: Forgot about that. I removed that piece of advice from the reply.